# Dump and Die function in laravel returns failed to load response data: no resource with given identifier in chrome browser

Tags: php, laravel-8

```
     {   dd($request->all());die;}
```

why dd doesn't return result and only show failed to load response data: no resource with given identifier in chrome browser?

Comment: i gave it a try to see if it work .

Comment: dd($request->all()); browser returns failed to load response data no content available from route call

Comment: You should look into your network tab. You can probably see a failed request there. If you click on it you can click on 'preview' to see the response which in your case should be the `dd()` output.

Comment: I am not getting any result if i use dd(), but if i use print_r the result is shown in network tab.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add `die` after `dd()`.

```
{ dd($request->all());die;}
```

S/B

```
{{ dd($request->all()); }}
```

OR

```
@dd($request->all());
```

Comment: I am trying it in controller not on blade file

Comment: Then use only dd($request->all());

Comment: it gives the same error....... in controller also

Comment: if return dd($request->all()); is given controller it shows error.

Comment: Could you please share the piece of code ?

Comment: public function project_dt_list(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }

Comment: Route::middleware(['Scopes:projects-list'])->get('project_dt_list', 'Project\Http\Controllers\ProjectController@project_dt_list'); this is my route call